# Hadoop - Unsupported Version while Running In Java 1.6

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using a Java code which needs Java version 7. When trying to run from Eclipse I got the error **Unsupported major.minor version 51.0**.

I found it's due to the version problem because when I run using version 6 I didn't get the above error. But my Java program needs version 7 to run. Is there any way to run this code? Please advice.

Note: I am running this code in remote machine and used Eclipse Editor.

Comment: A clear version conflict. Try clean and deploy again after changing to 1.7

Comment: I have changed the java codes to work on version 1.6. Thanks for your reply suresh